# How to optimize native JavaScript code when refactoring it from Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I need to rewrite some Jquery into native JavaScript code but I am facing a problem that I am not so sure how to solve.

This is Jquery code I need to rewrite in native JS:

```
$('.class1').click(function () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('.class2').css('top', '252px');
    $('.class3').css('bottom', '0px');
  }, 200);
  $('.class2').css('z-index', '-1');
  $('.class1').css('z-index', '-1');
});
```

And this is what I have written in native JavaScrip:

```
if (document.querySelector('.class1')){
document.querySelector('.class1').addEventListener('click', function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (document.querySelector('.class2')) {
            document.querySelector('.class2').style.top = '252px';
        }
        if ( document.querySelector('.class3')) {
            document.querySelector('.class3').style.bottom = '0px';
        }
    }, 200);
    if (document.querySelector('.class2')) {
        document.querySelector('.class2').style.zIndex = '-1';
    }
    if ( document.querySelector('.class1')) {
        document.querySelector('.class1').style.zIndex = '-1';
    }
})
}
```

I was hoping that people could explain to me how to solve two things:

1. Is there a more elegant way to check for an element on the current page if the code runs on the whole site?
2. Is there something else that I can replace those if statements inside the function?

   In Jquery those statements are executed one by one but in my case I need to check for an element first and if it is there do something with it.

Comment: `$(selector).css(...)` has two advantages: 1. if there's no match, there's no error 2. the css rule is applied to every matching element. `document.querySelector` otoh only returns the first match, so to reproduce (2) you need `document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(el => el.style.top = '252px');` which also solves (1)

Answer (score 1):

You can make the code more succinct by storing the result of `querySelector` within a variable. Also note that a class selector in jQuery can return multiple elements, so the native equivalent of it is `querySelectorAll()`.

As such you will need to loop through all the elements in that collection and add the event handlers, or update their style, as necessary. Due to this loop you don't need to explicitly check for the existence of the elements, as the `forEach()` will simply not execute if the collection is empty.

With that said, try this:

```js
let class1 = document.querySelectorAll('.class1');
let class2 = document.querySelectorAll('.class2');
let class3 = document.querySelectorAll('.class3');

class1.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      class2.forEach(el => el.style.top = '252px');
      class3.forEach(el => el.style.top = '0px');
    }, 200);
    
    class1.forEach(el => el.style.zIndex = -1);
    class2.forEach(el => el.style.zIndex = -1);
  });
});
```

Comment: One tiny other space saver, reduction with this `const qa = selector => document.querySelectorAll(selector);`